# Do I need this in my links type="value"?

Tags: css

Do I need to include type="value" in my page when linking my external style sheet or script? I thought I heard it was no longer needed in HTML5. I still see it in some html files. Still learning. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I see you already have a Stack Overflow account. This question belongs there. It will most likely be moved there shortly. Meanwhile, read through the faq here, and on Programmers so you know where to ask your question the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML5, `type` is not required either for [`<style>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-style-element) or for [`<script>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element). If the attribute is omitted, the defaults are `text/css` and `text/javascript` respectively.

Don't forget that in order for your pages to "be" HTML5, they need to start with the HTML5 [DOCTYPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```